# Palindrome with two functions - Mooc exercise

Tags: python

I'm doing the Palindromes exercise in Section 4 (Definite Iteration) of Part 4 of the Intro to Programming on mooc.fi.

the exercise states:

Please write a function named palindromes, which takes a string argument and returns True if the string is a palindrome. Palindromes are words which are spelled exactly the same backwards and forwards.

Please also write a main function which asks the user to type in words until they type in a palindrome:

NB:, the main function should not be within an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block

I have written a code but I'm facing an issue with the code not getting executed:

```
def palindromes (word: str):
    if word == word[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main (word):
    a= ""
    while a != "Paliindrome":
        word=input("Please type in a palindrome: ")
        check = palindromes(word)
        if word == "palindrome":
            break
        if check:
            print(f"{word} is a palindrome!")
        else:
            print("that wasn't a palindrome")
```

Comment: you need to call the main function. add `main()` to the end of your code and remove the `word` parameter from main, since you are getting this value inside the function.

Comment: Is this expected that your main function takes an argument? You don’t use it.
Is the validation tool working with `input`? Usually we don’t put a space between function name and arguments in signature and calls, maybe this is also the error.

Comment: the code works on other python compilers, when I run the TMC test for MOOC i get an error **Make sure you don't have an infinite loop in your code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def palindromes(word: str):
    return word == word[::-1]

def main():
    while True:
        word = input("Please type in a palindrome: ")
        if word == "exit":
            break
        if palindromes(word):
            print(f"{word} is a palindrome!")
        else:
            print("that wasn't a palindrome")

main()
```

I think it is better:)

#### 1.

`word == word[::-1]` is boolean and True or false and you dont need to check it,

#### 2.

get your input and check it for break condition and dont set parameter for main function

Comment: If you actually remove spacing between a function and their parameters, and add them between a variable being assigned, the value that is been assigned, and the `=`, it's even better!